# Unable to write Registry files using NSIS

Tags: installation, registry, nsis

I have the following code snippet used to write the registry files to the path :

```
;Registry and SDK Setup  
Section "mySection"  
    SetOverwrite on  
    SetOutPath "C:\ProgramData\....\Gadgets"  
    File "{....KEYS...}.png"  
    File "{....KEYS...}.xml"  
    WriteRegStr HKLM "...\STC\Gadgets\{....KEYS...}" "toastAction""DisableToast"  
SectionEnd
```

The above code fails to write the registry files. Could someone help me find the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [`$INSTDIR`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#varother) variable to indicate the destination directory. MUI 2 has a ready made page to let the user choose the destination folder. It's called `MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY`:

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"
Name "Test"
Outfile "test.exe"
InstallDir "$LOCALAPPDATA\test"

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Section
    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
    ;Use File to copy files to destination folder.

SectionEnd
```

Comment: You totally changed the original question. You should create a new question instead of that.